# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required

Tags: updating

Recently I updated from Drupal 7.38 to 7.39. It broke access to the site; the error message that i get is the following:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 
'/home/admin/domains/blahblahblah.info/public_html/blah/blah/includes/includes/database/select.inc' 
(include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') 
in /home/admin/domains/blahblahblah/public_html/blah/blah/includes/bootstrap.inc 
on line 3186
```

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: is this file exist: /home/admin/domains/blahblahblah.info/public_html/blah/blah/includes/includes/database/select.inc?

Comment: The error states what's going on; Drupal can't open the bootstrap code to get started. Most likely, it's a permissions issue where the web server can't open up bootstrap.inc for execution.

Comment: @ShawnConn Thank you very much for your response! I give 777 perimissions to this file (including execute) but the error still appear.

Comment: However, I did an update:
@sam2de: I updated the drupal core and now the file exists, but the error message changed into this:
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class InsertQuery in /home/admin/domains/ask4research.info/public_html/icalt/2016/includes/includes/database/query.inc on line 728